# Kafka Offsets.storage

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

What is the "offsets.storage" for `kafka 0.10.1.1`?

As per the documentation it shows up under [Old Consumer Configs](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/documentation.html#oldconsumerconfigs) as "zookeeper".

> offsets.storage zookeeper Select where offsets should be stored (zookeeper or kafka).

My consumer is `spring-boot-1.5.13 RELEASE` app which uses `kafka-clients-0.10.1.1` internally. As per the source code [ConsumerConfig.scala](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/670c70e18c91064e46cd4cd2d4b5d7a3476d5578/core/src/main/scala/kafka/consumer/ConsumerConfig.scala#L49), offsetStorage *is* "zookeeper", but when I run the consumer, I see the "`__consumer_offsets`" are getting created under `/tmp/kafka-logs` directory which is defined in `server.properties` [i.e. broker];

Moreover it doesn't show up under `zookeeper` ephemeral nodes, when I check with `zookeeper-shell.sh`.

`ls /consumers
[]`

**If the offsets.stroage is zookeeper, then why does the __consumer_offsets show up under /tmp/kafka-logs and doesn't show up in zookeeper ephemeral nodes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Kafka uses the "new" consumer (Java) not the old scala consumer.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Can you please guide me to the implementation as well?

Comment: Implementation of what, exactly?

Comment: The mechanism where "new" consumer is used.

Comment: Basically, which piece of code is using the "new" consumer.. If you please guide me to the implementation?

Comment: It's not clear how that's related to how offsets are stored. I suggest you read the [reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/). The component that uses the Java `Consumer` API is the [KafkaMessageListenerContainer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java).